# Is there a php (or composer) command to change upload_max_filesize && post_max_size from terminal?

Tags: configuration-management, php, shell-script, environment-variables, composer

Is there a `php` (or `composer`) terminal command to change the `php.ini` variables `upload_max_filesize` and `post_max_size from terminal` to some value directly from terminal, without `sed` or `awk` operations?

The reason; having a more a version-agnostic and more backward-compatible directive in my server-environment-establishment script, to change the values of these two variables.

### Update

If I'm not wrong utilizing the [confd](http://www.confd.io/) CM (supported in PHP >= 5.0) should be good (I can't test right now):

**1.** Create something like `/etc/php7/conf.d/local.ini`.

**2.** Add to it:

```
upload_max_filesize = 2000M
post_max_size = 2000M
```

Comment: Change them in your php application with `ini_set` ?

Comment: Do **not** use `ini_set`!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> The reason; having a more a version-agnostic and more
>   backward-compatible directive in my server-environment-establishment
>   script, to change the values of these two variables.

If you're trying to configure a server, you should use a configuration management system (Ansible, Puppet, Chef, Salt) or bake images for immutable infrastructure; trying to hack in pieces of configuration via PHP or bash or whatever will just make you unhappy.

Comment: I am sorry Xiong but it seems Ansible (which is helpful in so much) isn't very helpful in this particular case please look: https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/489281/changing-phps-post-max-size-and-upload-max-filesize-with-ansible/489342#489342

Comment: There isn't an Ansible module to change just that value, but I would throw the entire php.ini in a jinja template; you'll want to control it all anyways.

Comment: Oh curd, I linked to the answer instead to the question (which I'm sure you've seen)... Anyways, I have no idea what's a jinja template. If you have the spare time and will, I'll appreciate a short answer there - it would be helpful indeed...

Answer (score 1):

PHP has supported `conf.d` configuration subdirectories for ages now (cf. `PHP_INI_SCAN_DIR` in its documentation, this stuff is as old as PHP 5 basically) - allowing you to simply add a small file containing just the snippet of config you need in there, and as long as you make sure it's named so that it's ordered in a way it overrides the defaults, you're done.

IOW you don't go searching for an existing value to fiddle with, you just add your own.

Comment: Seems a great way, but it's strange for me no one mentioned it before you (also in AskUbuntu and I never came across `conf.d` in Apache, only in Nginx). Are you sure you don't mean to Nginx?... Please example what you will do in Apache...

Comment: These are all separate programs, all of which have their own method of including configuration subdirectories. Apache has used it with the name conf.d, before they switched to conf-available/enabled, and they effectively use the same thing with mods-available/enabled and sites-available/enabled. nginx uses it for conf.d, sites-available/enabled. php uses it for conf.d, in each of the SAPI config directories. It's actually quite widespread. There may be platform differences, though, I'm primarily referring here to Debian/Ubuntu.

Comment: Nice to know ! (I'm not a PHP programmer nor I know Apache well). I primarily use Debian Ubuntu. I upvoted your answer after this explanation as this seems promising. I encourage you to show an example of what you would have changed. Of course I'll accept this answer if it'll include a way that works for me well.

Comment: Have a look at e.g. https://stackoverflow.com/a/34724226/4617744

Answer (score 0):

You can use regex and after that change, you need to restart the webserver:

```
sed -i 's/upload_max_filesize\s*=.*/upload_max_filesize=100M/g' path/to/php.ini
sed -i 's/post_max_size\s*=.*/post_max_size=100M/g' path/to/php.ini
sed -i 's/memory_limit\s*=.*/memory_limit=512M/g' path/to/php.ini
```

But it is preferable to use **Configuration Management Tools**